# Error filtering multiple data using JDBC and javaFX

Tags: java

I will tell you about my problem. I have a database in mysql and I do the queries from Java using javafx and JDBC. I am trying to do a data filter, since I want to be able to filter data not only by name, but also by other data. As you can see, my code has many SQL statements, I tried to put them together in an array, but only the first statement works, if I do others, exceptions are thrown, it only works if I do only 1 individual query. My problem is that and I would like to find a solution. I have a lot of silenced code, since my idea is to have a statement that encompasses everything.

```
public static Comics[] filtadroBBDD(String nombreC, String numeroC, String varianteC, String firmaC,
            String nomEditorialC, String formatoC, String procedenciaC, String fechaC, String guionistaC,
            String nomDibujanteC) {

        reiniciarBBDD();

        String nombreCom, numeroCom, varianteCom, firmaCom, editorialCom, formatoCom, procedenciaCom, fechaCom,
                guionistaCom, dibujanteCom;
        Comics comics[] = null;

        String sql1 = "SELECT * FROM comicsbbdd where nomComic = '" + nombreC + "';";
        String sql2 = "SELECT * FROM comicsbbdd where numComic = '" + numeroC + "';";
        String sql3 = "SELECT * FROM comicsbbdd where nomVariante = '" + varianteC + "';";
        String sql4 = "SELECT * FROM comicsbbdd where firma = '" + firmaC + "';";
        String sql5 = "SELECT * FROM comicsbbdd where nomEditorial = '" + nomEditorialC + "';";
        String sql6 = "SELECT * FROM comicsbbdd where formato = '" + formatoC + "';";
        String sql7 = "SELECT * FROM comicsbbdd where procedencia = '" + procedenciaC + "';";
        String sql8 = "SELECT * FROM comicsbbdd where anioPubli = '" + fechaC + "';";
        String sql9 = "SELECT * FROM comicsbbdd where nomGuionistas = '" + guionistaC + "';";
        String sql10 = "SELECT * FROM comicsbbdd where nomDibujantes = '" + nomDibujanteC + "';";
//      String []sentenciasSQL = {sql1,sql2,sql3,sql4,sql5,sql6,sql7,sql8,sql9,sql10};
        String[] sentenciasSQL = { sql1 };

//      String sql = "SELECT * FROM comicsbbdd WHERE nomComic = '" + nombreC + "' AND numComic = '" + numeroC
//              + "' AND nomVariante = '" + varianteC + "' AND firma = '" + firmaC + "' AND nomEditorial = '"
//              + nomEditorialC + "' and formato = '" + formatoC + "' AND procedencia = '" + procedenciaC
//              + "' AND anioPubli = '" + fechaC + "' AND nomGuionista = '" + guionistaC + "' AND nomDibujante = '"
//              + nomDibujanteC + "';";

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < sentenciasSQL.length; i++) {
                ResultSet rs = DBManager.getComic(sentenciasSQL[i]);

                do {
                    nombreCom = rs.getString("nomComic");
                    numeroCom = rs.getString("numComic");
                    varianteCom = rs.getString("nomVariante");
                    firmaCom = rs.getString("firma");
                    editorialCom = rs.getString("nomEditorial");
                    formatoCom = rs.getString("formato");
                    procedenciaCom = rs.getString("procedencia");
                    fechaCom = rs.getString("anioPubli");
                    guionistaCom = rs.getString("nomGuionista");
                    dibujanteCom = rs.getString("nomDibujante");

                    FiltrolistComics.add(new Comics(nombreCom, numeroCom, varianteCom, firmaCom, editorialCom,
                            formatoCom, procedenciaCom, fechaCom, guionistaCom, dibujanteCom));

                } while (rs.next());
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
        comics = new Comics[FiltrolistComics.size()];
        comics = FiltrolistComics.toArray(comics);
        return comics;
    }

    public static void reiniciarBBDD() {
        FiltrolistComics.clear();
        listComics.clear();
    }
```

Comment: *if I do others, exceptions are thrown* - please add your stacktrace to your question.

Comment: Don't set parameters using string concatenation. That's just asking for trouble. Use a `PreparedStatement` with placeholders.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with JavaFX. You are just putting people on the wrong track.